# Details on mutual information equation

Tags: probability, mutual-information

I have been trying to implement mutual information in a java program that tries to identify terms that occur often together in documents. Basically, the program does the following: There is a text collection of just over 4.000.000 summaries from Wikipedia. This is searched through based on a query, resulting in a collection of say 100 texts that are deemed as a match to the query by Lucene index. I then create bigrams (structures of two words) so that all words are paired with all the other words in the result collection. Each bigram is then calculated a mutual information value for. The idea is that the highest scoring bigrams should be (hopefully) directly relevant to the original query.

On to how I understand the Mutual Information equation, which for the record looks like this:

P(x,y) * log(P(x,y) / (P(x) * P(y)),

where P(x,y) is the probability of term x and y occurring in a document, P(x) is the probability of just term x occurs in a document, and likewise for P(y) for term y.

I am unsure if I understand correctly what this means in terms of calculating the probability values. It is calculated by finding the frequency of a term divided by the number of articles in the result set. But is it the term frequency or the document frequency for a given term?

Ie. is P(x) in a result set of 100 articles the number of times term x occurs in the collection divided by 100? Or is it the number of articles in which term x occurs at least once divided by 100? And if it is the former, how then is P(x,y) calculated?

Answer (score 1):

P(x) is the number of document where x occurs divided by the number of documents. If it was the number of occurences of x divided by 100, then P(x) could be higher than one, which is against the definition of a probability.

P(x,y) is the number of documents where both x and y occurs divided by the number of documents.

You can also have a look at [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488817/pointwise-mutual-information-on-text).

Comment: This is what I expected, but my councillor tells me that I need to include the term frequency of terms x and y as well, and I just cannot see how that is done based on the equation examples I see. They all basically support what you just said. When I asked him he just simply said that I should view the documents as sets or vectors, but that didn't really help me at all..

Comment: Your councillor answer is strange because considering document as a set of words would remove term frequency information. In a set, a word is present only once.

Comment: I believe you need to use a kernel density estimator and calculate P(x) from there. meaning first you estimate the probability density function of your vector x and then calculating P(X) from this PDF. This P(X), is not the frequency of your word in the document, but is the probability of occurring P(X) in all documents.